# JpaRepository @Query comparision between date and Timestamp column not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CropTip extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "crop_id")
    Crop crop;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date tipDate;

    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date createdAt;

    public CropTip(Crop crop, String title, String description, Date tipDate) {
        this.crop = crop;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.tipDate = tipDate;
    }
 }
```

I want to select rows where tipDate is in a given range, and thus, I am using the following query within a JpaRepository:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT tip.* FROM crop_tip tip WHERE :lowerBound <= tip.tip_date AND tip.tip_date < :upperBound ORDER BY tip.tip_date DESC", nativeQuery = true)
List<CropTip> findLatestTips(Date lowerBound, Date upperBound);
```

I tried different approaches:

1. Native query
2. Non-native query
3. Spring data query method

None of them worked.
After a few experiments, I figured out that the Date parameters (lowerBound and upperBound) are being treated as simple dates (time is not taken into consideration).
Can someone help?

Comment: `private Date tipDate;` change its type to `java.sql.Timestamp` and give it a try

Comment: That did not work, unfortunately.
The parameters are being treated as simple date (time not taken into consideration).

Comment: Sorry, I missed the query method, if you did above suggestion, the method `Date lowerBound, Date upperBound` also needs to have the types changed

Comment: That didn't work either.
I tried to get rid of the upperBound parameter, and I got every row with `tipDate`'s day greater than or equal to `lowerBound`'s day. Apparently,  time is not being considered.